# Boilerplate Code for Subclassing UIViewController in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, subclass

With Xcode when you create a new Objective-C file with subclass Uiviewcontroller, you get a new file with all the boilerplate code ready to be edited. When I create a new file in swift, it's completely blank. Is this by design? How do I get the same template/boilerplate code so that I can get started coding quickly?

Comment: When you create a new file, choose "Cocoa Touch Class" instead of 
"Swift file" and it will use the boilerplate.

Comment: This should moved to and marked as the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Instead of creating a "Swift File", choose "Cocoa Class":

   [image]
2. Then choose the appropriate subclass:

   [image]
3. Finally click next and save to your desired location.

#### N.B.

You may need to change the import statement from `import Cocoa` to `import UIKit`